# Is there a way to create an XLSX with multiple sheets using alaSql?

Tags: javascript, alasql

What i´m trying to do is generating an xlsx file with multiple sheets by using alaSql . They only need to have the columns and no data at all (it´s going to be used as a template available for download)

```
    var tasksData = [{
        UserName:"",
        Application:"",
        Module:""
    }];
    var objectsData = [{
        UserName:"",
        Application:"",
        Module:""
    }];
    var conflictsData = [{
        UserName:"",
        Application:"",
        Module:""
    }];

    var opts = [{
        sheetid: 'TasksData',
        headers: false
        }, {
        sheetid: 'ObjectsData',
        headers: false
        }, {
        sheetid: 'ConflictsData',
        headers: false
        }];

        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("MatrixSODTemplate.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[tasksData,objectsData,conflictsData]]);
```

i need the output to be a single xlsx file with 3 sheets. And no data in it, only the columns.

Sheet  TaskData:
   -UserName
   -Application
   -Module

Sheet ObjectsData:
   -UserName
   -Application
   -Module

Sheet ConflictsData:
   -UserName
   -Application
   -Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found out what was going on. I had an old version of alasql in my project. So i upgrade it and then i found this helpfull link where the developers explain how to do it.

```
var data1 = [{a:1,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
var opts = [{sheetid:'One',header:true},{sheetid:'Two',header:false}];
var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("restest344b.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data1,data2]],
  function(){
    done();
  });
```

https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How-to-create-multiple-worksheets-into-a-workbook

Hope it helps someone